# how to use a figure in the table of contents instead of a title

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to use a figure (small icon) for a special section in the table of contents. Do you have any suggestion? 
typically I use  `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Name}`  for making the references to the table of contents.

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{filenameoftheimage}}` -- you have to protect `\includegraphics` since it's a fragile command. The scaling is up to you, of course, as well as horizontal etc. placement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's basically nothing specific about writing information to the `ToC` since it's a (special) `.tex` file -- however, as always, with writing to files, the content should be made robust or use `\protect` fragile commands, such as `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{beeduck}}
\section{Other foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Foo}
    \addsec[{\protect\includegraphics[width=1cm]{tiger}}]{}
    \section{Other foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is however a minor issue with this. on the output pdf, the bookmark name is "\includegraphics[width=1cm]{tiger}" . I could overcome this problem by using \texorpdfstring command

Comment: Yes, that is the right way if one needs the has bookmarks